# Httphandlers and http modules

Tags: asp.net

How do we findout the whether the application is using any HTTPModules and httphandler in the applicaion?

Is there anyway to findout from the url without checking the web.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check with any certainty without using backed code.

To get the current handler.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler
```

To get the list of modules that executed for the request

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules
```